# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x}\: dx$ using Limit of a Sum approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x}\: dx$ using Limit of a Sum approach.

Using the formula $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\:dx=(b-a) \times \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \times \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}\right)$$ we have

$$I=\int_{0}^{3} f(x)\:dx=(3-0) \times \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \times \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(0+\frac{(3-0)k}{n}\right)=3 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)$$ So

$$I=3\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{1+\frac{3k}{n}}$$ Now if we expand the summation we get limits of the form

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n}}+\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{n}}+\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{n}}+\cdots+\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{3n}{n}}$$

But each limit is clearly zero and hence $I=0$.  I know the answer is wrong but what is my mistake?

Comment: You wrote that you "expanded the summation", but the following equation has the limit "distributed" over each term, and this operation in general does not give an equivalent expression. (Worse, the number of terms in the sum itself depends on $n$...)

Comment: You have infinitely many terms in the limit. You cannot say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{1}{n}=\lim\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\lim\frac{1}{n}=0+\dots+0=0$.

Comment: yes i got it now there are infinite such summations so $0 \times \infty$ is indeterminate and not zero. But now how to evaluate the limit can i have a hint

Comment: Why Dont you want any simpler approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

$$\int_0^3 \sqrt{1+x} \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1 + \frac{3k}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{n + 3k}.$$

Using the binomial expansion, we have

$$(n + 3k - 3)^{3/2} = (n + 3k)^{3/2} \left(1 - \frac{3}{n+3k} \right)^{3/2} \\ = (n + 3k)^{3/2}\left(1 - \frac{3}{2}\frac{3}{n+3k}  + O(1/n^2)\right),$$

and

$$\sqrt{n+3k} = \frac{2}{9}\left[(n+3k)^{3/2} - (n+3k-3)^{3/2}\right] +O(1/\sqrt{n}).$$

Summing we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{n + 3k} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2}{9}\left[(n+3k)^{3/2} - (n+3k-3)^{3/2}\right] \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{n^{3/2}}\frac{2}{9}\left[(4n)^{3/2} - (n)^{3/2}\right] \\ = \frac{2}{3}\left[4^{3/2} - 1\right].$$

Comment: thanks that was pretty nice method

Comment: @Umeshshankar: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose the partition points $x_k$ such that $\sqrt{1+x_k}$ becomes manageable. Therefore put
$$x_k:=u_k^2-1\quad(0\leq k\leq n)$$ whereby the $$u_k:=1+{k\over n}\quad(0\leq k\leq n)$$
are equally spaced. The $x_k$ are then inequally spaced between $0$ and $3$, but in any case the differences $x_k-x_{k-1}$ tend to $0$ when $n\to\infty$. A typical Riemann sum is then given by
$$\eqalign{R_n&:=\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+x_k}\>(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k(u_k+u_{k-1})(u_k-u_{k-1})\cr &={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+{k\over n}\right)\left(2+{2k-1\over n}\right)={14\over3}+{3\over2n}-{1\over 6n^2}\ .\cr}$$
Note that we have computed the last sum exactly, using the formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha$ when $\alpha\in\{0,1,2\}$. It follows that
$$\int_0^3\sqrt{1+x}\>dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n={14\over3}\ .$$

Comment: could you tell me how $u_k=1+\frac{k}{n}$